# Angular 2 Material - Place holder issue with setValue

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design

I am having an issue with Angular2's material components when a component is updated via setValue.  Here is the plnkr....

https://embed.plnkr.co/lZhHJKBhuldUqzUt9Q18/

You can see that the value and the placeholder are both occupying the same space.

With the setTimeout, I'm emulated an ajax fetch that would populate the form asynchronously.  Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with ng2's material module?

Comment: If it's one ajax fetch, the pattern I've seen is your component subscribes to the response and initializes the form when it receives the response. Then the form field is initialized with the response value (e.g. `text: 'Sushi'`). Does that match your use case?

Comment: @stealththeninja not really as this is just a simple case, in my real world application, the form will be loaded, then another field may get updated based on another selection within the form, in that example, I wouldn't want to dispose of the entire formGroup, to update a single component

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was a bug that was fixed, just not yet pushed out via NPM...

https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/2455